# I want to disable the button if specific text has been found in form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hEv9.jpg)

This Screenshot is my form submission, and "Final" is data entered in text field.
Edit Button is always show/ enable.
In this case, I want to disable the Edit button if "Final" has been found in form submission.

I have no idea how to create the best code for this.
I hope anybody can help me by code here.
thx.

note:

ID of Edit button is "ipt_fsqm_report_print_9" .

I cannot find ID of "Final" text.

Comment: show some efforts first...come up with some code

Comment: Please provide some html of that form(including "Final" text part) so we can help you.

Comment: I use  form builder plugin for wordpress. so, to make the field just drag n drop.  Maybe you can help me with jquery code by this logic : If text "Final" found, then disable Edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's text "Final", then hide "Edit" button.
I've found my answer by this code =

```
if($('p:contains("Final")').length > 0){
    $('button:contains("Edit")').hide();
}
```